# I can't access to variables filled trough httpclient observable subscription

Tags: angular-httpclient, angular2-observables, angular10

I'm tryin to use httpclient but once I have subscribed to the service and I get the right values I can not access to the variable where I have the values

```
proyecto: Proyecto;

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private service: ProyectoService
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
 const id = params['id'];
 this.service.getDatosProyectoCabecera(id)
  .subscribe(
  (data: Proyecto) => this.proyecto = data,
  (err: any) => console.log(err),
  () => console.log('Recogidos los datos del proyecto para la cabecera')
 );
 
console.log(this.proyecto);
```

this last console.log prints "undefined"

How can I use this.proyecto to any issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't call a subscribe within a subscribe, it's an anti-pattern.
Use a higher observable instead:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.route.params.pipe(
     mergeMap(params => {
         const id = params['id'];
         return this.service.getDatosProyectoCabecera(id)
     })
 ).subscribe(
     (data: Proyecto) => this.proyecto = data,
     (err: any) => console.log(err),
     () => console.log('Recogidos los datos del proyecto para la cabecera')
 );
}
```

What do you mean about this?

> this last console.log prints "undefined"

I see only two console.log. One that should print if there's an error and one when your observable completes. In this case, to make sure your observable complete, you can add `take(1)` in you pipe to emit only one value and complete the observable.